# flutter upi transaction not working (error)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, upi

UPI not working in a flutter, I tried much time into my app with differents UPI app and different library from pub.dev

upi_india (not working) upi_pay (not working) flutter_upi (not working)

Errors :

1. Too many attempts more than 10 time
2. Risk threshold exceed
3. Payment failure (code : U16)
4. you've exceeded maximum transaction amount set by your bank

GPay, BHIM, PhonePe, PayTm all transactions failed in this apps using with flutter 3rd party upi libraries

Some of the libraries are discontinued from pub.dev

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for a flutter library `upi_pay` the issue is not on the side of the library but on the side of UPI

A simple solution that works for me was to create a Google Pay business account via [Google Pay Business](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.merchant) app

Associate your bank account with it

After your account is reviewed, you will get an UPI ID

Then use this new business UPI ID as recipient UPI Id and receiver name as  display name inside Gpay business account

Steps for [Google Business Registration](https://support.google.com/pay/business/answer/7530745?hl=en&ref_topic=7684388&visit_id=637416327039382550-1174538054&rd=1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use razorpay for payment gateaways it supports Bhim UPI, card, Netbanking, Wallets and in addition it is easy to implement.

Comment: do they charge tn fee for upi payments. for other payments I know its 2-3% they charge?

Comment: I have implemented it they give us offers on emails where they allow more than lakhs of transections without any fee. You can check my signing up and wait for email then apply.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the package is unusable as mentioned on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india).Check [this](https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/UPI-Plugin-Flutter/issues/32) github issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Issue is not with your code, Same issue I am facing in Ionic, Until 3 weeks back, it used to work fine.
- Looks like most the UPI apps (GooglePay, AmazonPay, BHIM, PhonePe) are blocking transactions initiated outside application.
- As of Nov 26, 2020. Only ICICI iMobile app is allowing the payment
- So you can try ICICI iMobile app or use your bank's native application

Comment: Yes on point. Do you have any workaround for the same?

Comment: What I have noticed is only person to person payment is blocked. person to merchant is still allowed. I spoke to customer support of Google and PayTM both told it is not something they can change now.

Comment: Oh very good observation, I will look into that.